# Как поменять тип сборки проекта в Delphi 10.2 на Release?

Tags: delphi

Delphi 10.2:
Выставляю в свойствах проекта "*Target: Release configuration - All platforms*", сохраняю свойства, ожидаю при сборке получить Релизный экзешник меньшего размера, ну и сообщение `Building MyProject.dproj(Release, Win32)`, но при запуске Build в логах все равно запись:

> Building MyProject.dproj(Debug, Win32)

Как поменять тип сборки проекта с Дебаг на Релиз?

Comment: Окей, а что вы ожидали, что хотите получить?

Comment: Экзешник меньшего размера, например получить. Ну и сообщение Building MyProject.dproj(Release, Win32)

Comment: В свойствах проекта выставляются настройки типов сборок. А сам тип сборки задается как ниже написал @zed, в другом месте.

Answer (score 3):

Тип сборки (Build Configuration) легко задаётся и переключается через Project Manger (правая нанелька):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В хелпе даже справка по этому поводу есть: [Activating a Build Configuration for a Project](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Activating_a_Build_Configuration_for_a_Project)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понятно!

Comment: @AVM Если вопрос решён, отмечайте ответ галочкой.